# What is the weak derivative of $|x|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I know that $|x|\in W^{1,1}(-1,1)$ and that $$|x|'=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$$
what what is the derivative at $x=0$ ?

Comment: It's not classically differentiable at $0$, and weak derivatives don't really make sense at a point. A weak derivative is a functional. If you choose to identify a weak derivative with integration against another function, that function is unique only up to null sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative#Examples